# Control of Angle in Google VR

Tags: google-vr

I'm testing the Google VR kit, the idea is to just control the camera looking forward. Is there a way to limit how much can the camera turn while using using GoogleVR SDK? Or the default is a 360 angle view?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? If you really want to restrict the viewing angle, you are going to have some very angry users.

Answer (score 0):

The Google VR SDK just gives you data about the head tracking (Quaternions, Rotation matrix, etc...). Basically, in a GvrView (which is the base view in the Google VR SDK), the Google VR SDK does NOTHING with the camera. It does NOT move it.

It is up to you, in your renderer (Renderer or StereoRenderer - attached to your GvrView), to use these data to control your camera in the 3D scene. You can apply the head transformation to your camera so it can follow the user's head movements or ignore these movements and have a static camera or ...

The thing to get is that the Google VR SDK works with Open GL ES. You render a 3D Scene using Open GL ES and the Google VR SDK comes at the end to post process your rendering in order to have it good-looking with a cardboard.

I repeat, the Google VR SDK do not manage the rendering or the camera. It is up to the developper to manage those thing using the context and the data the SDK provides.

PS : If you use a VrPanoWidget or VrVideoView (which are views that already manage the rendering of an image or a video), you might not be able to control the camera at all and i think that you can only have 360° camera because these components can only handle 360° videos or images.